# Groovy: receiver-modifying equivalent of collect()?

Tags: arrays, groovy, collections

I need to loop through an array and perform a function on each element.  After this operation I will no longer need the original array.  Does Groovy have a way to modify the original array *in place*, without creating a new object?

For example, instead of

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = a.collect { elem -> elem * 2 }
```

I want to do:

```
a.collectInPlace { elem -> elem * 2 }
```

So that `a` becomes `[2, 4, 6]`

In Ruby for example, the array class has a `#collect` method, which returns the modified array, and also `#collect!`, which modifies the array in place and returns `nil`.

Comment: Why would you want to? You would lose any firm of thread safety at the premium of saving a tiny amount of memory

Comment: And returning null from the method would stop you having any sort of fluency in your code

Comment: I don't agree with the point on code fluency (I think the extra assignment is messy), and thread safety is not an issue for me, whereas speed and memory efficiency are

Comment: My point about fluency is that you can do `a.collect { it * 2 }.findAll { it % 3 }.inject { a, b -> a + b }`.  With your version, you can't chain things together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Groovy does not provide such a method. But, you can create your own. It may be a terrible idea, but you can still do it :) Here's an example:

```
/*
 * A Groovy category to add collectInPlace()
 * to the List interface.
 */
class ListCategory {

    /*
     * Calls the Closure for each element in the List
     * and replaces the element with the output of the
     * Closure.
     */
    static List collectInPlace(List list, Closure closure) {
        (0..<list.size()).each { index ->
            list[index] = closure(list[index])
        }

        return list
    }
}

def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b

use(ListCategory) {
    b = a.collectInPlace { elem -> elem * 2 }
}

assert a.is(b) // Groovy's Object.is(Object) is the equivalent of Java's == operator.
assert b == [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel!  I'll have another look in a day or two.  Please can you explain why you think it is/may be a terrible idea?  I'm pretty new to Groovy and I found the self-modifying methods in Ruby very convenient

Comment: or just: `List.metaClass.collectInPlace = { Closure closure -> list.eachWithIndex { it, idx -> delegate[idx] = closure(it) } ; null }` in place of the Category and the `use` block requirement

Comment: @charrison, it's a terrible idea because working with immutable objects is safer. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02183/